EAS Build says Cocoapods is not available
When I run eas build --profile development --platform ios --local, I get this error:
Cocoapods is not available, make sure it's installed and in your PATH
pod --version exited with non-zero code: 1
npx exited with non-zero code: 1

Its very annoying, I have cocoapods installed and Im very confused as to why this doesnt work
When I run pod --version in my mac terminal, returns 1.15.2.

For me, the issue was resolved by making a couple of changes:

Avoid using sudo: I found that running the build command without sudo worked better. CocoaPods tends to have issues when run with sudo, and it might give you warnings. Try running eas build --profile development --platform ios --local without sudo and see if that helps.

Change ownership of directories: I also changed the ownership of any directories related to the build, like .npm, .expo, and .app-store, in my root directory. Sometimes, during the build process, you might encounter ownership and permission errors, especially with these directories. You can resolve this by running:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.expo
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.app-store



After making these changes, the build process worked as expected. Hopefully, this helps you too!
